# how to align rows in datafrane after pd.concat() Python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 single column dataframes, after perform a LEFT JOIN using pd.conca, first column value doesn't align with the second one

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'city':['ABC','NEW','TWIN','KING']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'city':['NEW','ABC']})
```

[image]

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

[image]

my expected result

[image]

I know I can sort it, but I wanna know how to do something similar to SQL LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
pd.concat([e.set_index(e['city']) 
           for e in [df1, df2]], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   city city
0   ABC  ABC
1   NEW  NEW
2  TWIN  NaN
3  KING  NaN
```

Creating a index with the city columns for each dataframe, then pd.concat which pandas aligns the data based on index and lastly drop the index.

Note, `set_index(dataframe[column])` *duplicates* the column in the index, where `set_index(column)` *moves* the column to the index.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which uses `pd.merge` instead of `pd.concat`:

```
df1.merge(df2.assign(city2=df2['city']), on='city', how='left')
```

Output:

```
   city city2
0   ABC   ABC
1   NEW   NEW
2  TWIN   NaN
3  KING   NaN
```